# how to get phone number of selected person in contacts

Tags: iphone

I need to get phone number from contacts.

For that my code is

```
- (IBAction)contacts {

    NSLog(@"contacts clicked ");

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePickerController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    peoplePickerController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:peoplePickerController animated:NO];
    [peoplePickerController release];

}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    NSString *number = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    NSLog(@" %@",number);
    return YES;
}
```

here it displays in console like this

```
ABMultiValueRef 0x740b680 with 1 value(s)
    0: _$!<Mobile>!$_ (0x7419880) - (929) 230-8622 (0x740b490)
```

Here `(929) 230-8622` is mobile number,How can i get only mobile number.

After selecting contact i need to close this view controller.

For that i write code like this

[self dissmissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

But it shows waning that myclass may not respond to dissmissModalViewController.

How can i done that after selection i need to close this view controller.

can anyone pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolve my problem using By Adding this code.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        CFStringRef phonenumberselected = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, identifier);
        CFStringRef emailLabelSelected = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, identifier);
        CFStringRef emailLabelSelectedLocalized = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, identifier));
        NSLog(@"\n EmailValueSelected = %@ \n EmailLabelSelected = %@ \n \EmailLabeSelectedlLocalized = %@", phonenumberselected, emailLabelSelected, emailLabelSelectedLocalized);

        NSString *aNSString = (NSString *)phonenumberselected;



        [ self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
        return NO;
    }   
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helpful who face problem like me.

Comment: This behaves very strangely in some cases... In cases of contacts with two numbers it phonenumberselected is the mobile number if you select the home number, and it returns null if you select the mobile number... Any idea what the problem is!? I've used exactly the same code as you...

Answer (score 2):

write below code in your

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

{       

    ABMultiValueRef mul;
    mul=(NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    int count= ABMultiValueGetCount(mul);
    NSString *name=(NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mul,0);

}
```

Comment: count variable is just to know how many Phone nos you have for that particular contact